# Proving the validity of a metric on $X \sqcup Y$.

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the below problem.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces and consider the set $Z := X \sqcup Y$. Let $C$ be a positive constant. Define a function $\rho: Z \times Z \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ by
> \begin{cases} 
> & \rho_Z (x_1, x_2) = \rho_X (x_1, x_2) \\ 
> &  \rho_Z (y_1, y_2) = \rho_Y (y_1, y_2) \\ 
> & \rho_Z (x,y) = \rho(y,x) = C. 
> \end{cases}
> Show that $\rho$ is a metric if and only if for any $x_1, x_2 \in X$ and $y_1, y_2 \in Y$, we have
> $$ 
> \rho_X (x_1, x_2) \leq 2C \text{ and } \rho_Y (y_1, y_2) \leq 2C.
> $$

My first thought is that $X$ and $Y$ are not required to be disjoint, so the definition of $Z$ is a bit uncertain. In this case, I believe disjoint union is defined by taking isomorphic copies of $X$ and $Y$ were the elements are distinct, e.g., by replacing $x$ with $(x,0)$ or some similar construction. This does present a question of whether I need to test for consistency across definitions for elements $x_1 \in X \cap Y$ (or $y_1 \in X \cap Y$). Otherwise, the metric is not well-defined. Since it's given as a well-defined functions, I assume these complications have been assumed away, but I can't say that I fully understand how. In other words, does the definition quietly replace $X$ with $X'$ and $Y$ with $Y'$, where $X \cong X'$ and $Y \cong Y'$ as sets, update the distance function, and then take $x_1, x_2 \in X'$ and $y_1, y_2 \in Y'$?

Here is my attempt at a proof.

> ($\Leftarrow$) Suppose for any $x_1, x_2 \in X$ and $y_1, y_2 \in Y$, we have $\rho_X (x_1, x_2) \leq 2C$ and $\rho_Y (y_1, y_2) \leq 2C$. We check that $\rho$ gives a metric on $Z$.
>
> By definition, for any $z_1, z_2 \in Z$, $\rho(z_1, z_2) \geq 0$. If $z_1 = z_2$, then we either have $z_1 = z_2$ in $X$ or $z_1 = z_2$ in $Y$. (This assumes $X$ and $Y$ have been replaced with isomorphic copies that are disjoint, but I still am not fully clear on this step.) Since $\rho_X$ and $\rho_Y$ are metrics on $X$ and $Y$, respectively, the former yields $\rho_Z (z_1, z_2) = \rho_X (z_1, z_2) = 0$ and the latter yields $\rho_Z (z_1, z_2) = \rho_Y (z_1, z_2) = 0$.
>
> By definition (the third line in the definition), $\rho_Z$ is symmetric.
>
> Let $z_1, z_2, z_3 \in Z$. We must show that
> $$
> \rho_Z (z_1, z_2) \leq \rho_Z (z_1, z_3) \leq \rho_Z (z_2, z_3)$. 
> $$
> This also seems to be "inherited" by restricting to either $X$ or $Y$ and using the triangle inequality established on $\rho_X$ and $\rho_Y$. I haven't used the assumption, so I must be doing something wrong, and the trick must be in mixing elements of $X$ and $Y$.
>
> ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose that $\rho$ is a metric. Then for any $x,y \in Z$, we have $\rho_Z (x,y) = C \leq 2C$ since $C > 0$. This is true regardless of whether $x,y$ originally lived in $X$ or $Y$.

The above proof sounds almost trivial, so I think I could also be misunderstanding the definition there.

Comment: Yes, the disjoint union is exactly the thing you are talking about. (Take the isometric copies of $X$ and $Y$ so that they *don't* intersect.) As for your proof, you need to take into account the possibility $d_Z(x_1, y)+d_Z(y,x_2)\ge d_Z(x_1,x_2)$ for $x_1,x_2\in X, y\in Y$ (i.e. the "mixing"). It is not making it easier that the problem itself is a bit ill-posed: they assume that all $x$'s belong to $X$ and all $y$'s belong to $Y$, without saying. (E.g. $\rho_Z(x,y)=\rho_Z(y,x)=C$ **for every** $x\in X, y\in Y$; the last bit is obviously assumed but not spelled out!).

Comment: @StinkingBishop I don't think I understand why we would require $x \in X$, $y \in Y$. Could you explain a bit more about why this is needed?

Comment: Because that is what the problem statement says (i.e. tries to say). In other words, this is (I claim here) an unspoken condition in your problem. Without it, the problem doesn't make sense. E.g. if $x,y$ can be any elements from $X\sqcup Y$, then one possibility would be that $x=y$ . How do you reconcile that with $\rho_Z(x,y)=C$?

Comment: It makes sense that I can't have $x = y$ in that case because then $\rho_Z (x,y) = 0$ (or it would have to is $\rho_Z$ is a metric. But why can't they be two different elements from $X$ or two different elements from $Y$?

Comment: See, you have to tweak the conditions one way or another. Let's think... Assume both $x,y\in X$. How do you reconcile $\rho_Z(x,y)=C$ with $\rho_Z(x,y)=\rho_X(x,y)$ (first condition, renaming $x_1,x_2$ as $x,y$)? And so on. The only way I can see that the problem makes sense is to assume $x_1,x_2,x\in X,y_1,y_2,y\in Y$, i.e. that whoever posed the problem was a bit careless with notation.

Comment: (If in doubt, you will need to ask whoever posed that problem to you whether you can assume all $x$'s to be from $X$ and all $y$'s from $Y$, I bet they will say "sure, yes, oh, did I forget to specify that?")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of the disjoint union is specifically designed to let you **assume** that $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint subsets of $Z = X \sqcup Y$.

You could choose to avoid that assumption and to work with the set theoretic formalities of the disjoint union, but I would only advise doing that if you can avoid tying yourself in knots (don't work with $X$ and $Y$ themselves, instead work with $X' = \{(x,0) \mid x \in X\}$ with the metric on $X$ transported to $X'$; and similarly work with $Y' = \{(y,1) \mid y \in Y\}$).

Anyway, if you are willing to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint subsets of $Z = X \sqcup Y$, then your proof is perfectly fine as far as it goes, and as you observe it's rather a trivial matter, and there's nothing wrong with that. However, you do have a gap in your proof. Letting $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in Z$, you should be more careful to break into cases depending on which of $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are in $X$ and which are in $Y$, which makes 8 cases in all. For example: in the case that $z_1 \in X$ and $z_2 \in Y$ and $z_3 \in X$ we have $d(z_1,z_2) + d(z_2,z_3) = C + C = 2C$, and $d(z_1,z_3) \le 2C$.

Comment: Am I allowed to say, "without loss of generality, assume that $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint; otherwise, replace them with isometric copies?" My understanding is that the definition of disjoint union already replaces $X$ with $X'$ and $Y$ with $Y'$; otherwise, I can't define a disjoint union. Also, is it possible that $(x,0) = (y,1)$ for some $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$? I know that $0$ and $1$ are just given as demonstrations, but should I require that I replace $x \in X$ with $(x,x')$ with $x' \not \in Y$ and $y \in Y$ with $(y,y')$ where $y' \not \in X$?

Comment: By definition of ordered pairs, $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ AND $b=d$. So, $(x,0)=(y,1)$ if and only if $x=y$ AND $0=1$, which is false, thereby proving that $(x,0) \ne (y,1)$. That is the point of disjoint union: it is a completely simple and straightforward construction, using the inequality $0 \ne 1$ and the definition of ordered pairs, to construct isomorphic copies $X',Y'$ of $X,Y$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint. If for some reason one objected to the use of $0$ and $1$, one could choose any other two mathematical objects which are known to be *not equal to* each other.

Comment: That makes much more sense, thank you. Lastly am I correct that I can assume $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint "without loss of generality"?

Comment: Yes, that is a common practice.